# Delphi´s utf8encode including \r\n at end of string

Tags: delphi

I need to post some data to a web service from my Delphi app. In short what I´m doing is this

```
http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
params := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
params.AddFormField('param', utf8encode('value'));
http.Post('myurl', params);
```

In the server log I get this

```
{"param"=>"value\r\n"}
```

I don´t know if it is utf8encode or TidHTTP.post that is including the CRLF at the end of the string. Any idea on how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: To verify, try a simple hand-written HTML form with a param input field. Or use Synapse to send the same request, and see if the server still has the extra characters. Or use Fiddler.

Comment: @mjn I made the test using curl, the server did not include the '\r\n' and as Andreas said, it is not utf8encode so it only remains TidHTTPClient... I guess it is it that is adding the \r\n. Don´t know why though

Comment: My default answer for Indy question now will be: "use the latest version!" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdHTTP` and `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` do not add extra line breaks unnecessarily.  Also, the fact that you are encoding the text manually tells me you are likely using an older version of Indy. In the current 10.5.8 SVN revision, `AddFormField()` has an `ACharset` parameter, which sets the `TIdFormDataField.CharSet` property, so `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` can encode text internally for you when needed, eg:

```
http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);   
params := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;   
params.AddFormField('param1', 'value1', 'utf-8');   
params.AddFormField('param2', 'value2', 'utf-8');   
params.AddFormField('param3', 'value3', 'utf-8');   
http.Post('myurl', params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation showed that TidHTTPClient and TIdMultiPartFormDataStream includes the '\r\n' to the last added param. For instance

```
http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
params := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
params.AddFormField('param1', utf8encode('value1'));
params.AddFormField('param2', utf8encode('value2'));
params.AddFormField('param3', utf8encode('value3'));
http.Post('myurl', params);
```

results in

```
{"param1"=>"value1", "param2"=>"value2", "param3"=>"value3\r\n"}
```

Adding a

```
params.AddFormField('', '');
```

after all params solves the problem. Not the ideal solution but it´s ok for now.

Comment: Maybe your Indy version is not up to date (current is 10.5.8)

Comment: Seems like a standard artifact of the way HTTP, SMTP and other RFC protocols work. You are after all sending and receiving a block of text, split into lines, and perhaps the code that is receiving the data on the other side relies on the cr+lf existing.

Comment: If the same did not happen with curl POST (using -d parameter) as you wrote, I guess it is a bug in your Indy version. Maybe Indy sends a trailing \r\n while curl uses \n, or something like that.